# Is it safe to run an applicaton written in Java 6 with Java 7?

Tags: java, java-7, java-6

I am working on an ERP system that was written in Java 6.

On startup it is enforced that Java 6 is used with code like this:

```
if (!System.getProperty("java.version").startsWith("1.6"))
    // terminate
```

As far as I'm aware, Java 7 is designed to be able to run applications that were developed in earlier versions.

Should it be relatively safe to "break" this check? What are the problems I could run into?

Comment: Do you have tests for your application?

Comment: Java 7 will be EOL April 2015 - go straightforward to Java 8 and .... test ist ... http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/eol-135779.html

Comment: I think it is likely that your code would run correctly in a Java 7 VM, but it is not certain.  You are more likely to have trouble with behavior changes in the standard library than with changes in the VM itself.  I had exactly such an issue with `BigDecimal` between (I think) Java 1.4 and Java 1.5.  As @Maxim implied, this sort of thing is what automated tests are for.

Comment: I would say use java6 only unless your erp vendor provides you a release compatible wtih java7 (communicate with them about this), with java7 It might work fine but you never know what breaks in future(may be due to very minor issues) . if made your mind to use java7, then you should do regression testing of your application.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Should it be relatively safe to "break" this check? What are the problems I could run into?

Yes. I would assume that check is to prevent you from running on earlier versions (or unsupported versions). It could stop working. And, it might violate any support contracts you have. It's possible they're using JNI or JNA to do something with incompatible native libraries. It's possible they're using custom object serialization that won't work.

Of course, it might work. We can't guarantee it (or test it for you).